# Why can't I install "Open As Administrator"?

Tags: software-installation, administrator

I tried following this tutorial:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install open-as-administrator
```

But I keep getting this [error](http://pastebin.com/LPG9GD8j).

Any idea what might be the cause? I'm using Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Try making the directory first `mkdir /home/dorian/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Open_as_Administrator -p` and then `sudo apt-get install open-as-administrator`

Comment: And file a bug report at noobslab.  This shouldn't be happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like there might be a problem with the package itself (specifically, one of the installation scripts). I'd try contacting the PPA maintainer and see if it is a problem they need to fix.

Comment: Because of unknown reasons, it seems it works. Thanks anyway!